# Prove that the operator $Ax(t)= \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds + x(t)$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}.$ $A:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Prove that the operator $$Ax(t)= \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds  + x(t)$$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}.$
$$A:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$$
The metric on $C[0,1]$ is $\max_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|$

For the operator to be invertible this has to apply for every function

$ x(t) \in C[0,1]: \exists m \text{ such that } \|Ax(t)\|_{C[0,1]}\geq m\|x(t)\|_{C[0,1]}$

I have that:

$$ \|Ax(t)\|_{C[0,1]} = \max_{t\in [0,1]}|\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds  + x(t)|$$
How can I find an $m$ so that this applies for every $x \in C[0,1]$

Comment: The fact that the operator $Vx(t) = \int_0^t\! x(s)\,ds$ is quasinilpotent may prove useful, (i.e. if $N$ is quasinilpotent then $1 + N$ is invertible).

Answer (score 3):

To solve the inverse equation, $Ax=y$ for $x$:
$$
                 \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds+x(t) = y(t) \\
         \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds+\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds = y(t) \\
              \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t}\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds\right)=e^ty(t) \\
            e^{t}\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds = \int_{0}^{t}e^{s}y(s)ds \\
             \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds = e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{s}y(s)ds \\
                   x(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{s}y(s)ds\right) \\
         x(t)=y(t)-\int_{0}^{t}e^{s-t}y(s)ds.
$$
The inverse $A^{-1}$ applied to $y$ is given by right side of the above. It's straightforward to check that $(A^{-1}y)(t)=y(t)-\int_{0}^{t}e^{s-t}y(s)ds$ is a bounded operator on $C[0,1]$.