# Find inverse operator of $Tx(t)=x(t)+t^2\int_0^1 s x(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=(C[0,1],||\cdot||_\infty)$ and $(Ax)(t)=x(t)+\int_0^1 t^2s x(s)ds$, and $A:X\to X$, how to find $A^{-1}$

If it were not definite integral I could have changed it to the differential equation but I cannot do anything

I found the following link but cannot apply because again it is not indefinite integral in the equation.

[Prove that the operator $Ax(t)= \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds + x(t)$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}.$ $A:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267231/prove-that-the-operator-axt-int-0txsds-xt-is-invertible-and-fin)

Answer (score 2):

If we multiply this by $t$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$, we get

$$\int_0^1tTx(t)dt=\int_0^1tx(t)dt+\left(\int_0^1t^3dt\right)\left(\int_0^1sx(s)ds\right)=\frac{5}{4}\int_0^1sx(s)ds$$

We change the integration variable from $t\mapsto s$ on the left and then multiply by $4t^2/5$ and get

$$\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1sTx(s)ds=t^2\int_0^1sx(s)ds=Tx(t)-x(t)$$

We can then solve for $x(t)$ as a function of $Tx(t)$ and get

$$x(t)=Tx(t)-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1sTx(s)ds$$

or,

$$T^{-1}y(t)=y(t)-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1sy(s)ds$$

To check this,

$$T^{-1}Tx(t)=Tx(t)-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1sTx(s)ds=x(t)+t^2\int_0^1sx(s)ds-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1s\left(x(s)+s^2\int_0^1ux(u)du\right)$$

$$=x(t)+t^2\int_0^1sx(s)ds-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1sx(s)ds-\frac{4}{5}t^2\int_0^1\int_0^1s^3ux(u)du$$

$$=x(t)+\frac{1}{5}t^2\int_0^1sx(s)ds-\frac{1}{5}t^2\int_0^1ux(u)du=x(t)$$

and we can show this similarly for $TT^{-1}y(t)=y(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to find the operator $T^{-1}$ such that $T^{-1}Tx(t) = TT^{-1}x(t) = x(t),$ for all $x(t).$

Comment: I tried now but for this case it is very hard can you give me more info?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Write $$h(t) =x(t) +t^2\int_0^1 x(s)ds$$

Note that by derivating 3 times you get something interesting.

and solve for $x=f(h) $

Using variation of parameter if necessary.