# What are the uses for operators comprised of integration adjoined with the identity?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Another poster was inspired to ask this question [Prove that the operator $Ax(t)= \int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds + x(t)$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}.$ $A:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267231/prove-that-the-operator-axt-int-0txsds-xt-is-invertible-and-fin?rq=1) .

In one form or another, this related to their learning, or some problem they were studying.

My questions are: what are the practical or theoretical applications of finding the inverse operator of $$Ax(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t}x(s)ds + x(t) = \left(\int + I \right)[x(t)]$$?

Why would a professor assign a homework problem like this? Or alternatively, why might someone be researching it?

Comment: To learn how to find the inverse of operators?

Comment: But why would you ever want to know how to find an inverse of this type of operator or of this particular form? What is it used for?

Comment: One could ask this exact same question for pretty much any of the hundred of thousands of questions in the site.

Comment: Perhaps they should ask that, they asker didn't provide context or history for the question as many others often as for.

Comment: Well, the equation $Ax=f$ is (for differentiable $f$) equivalent to the initial value problem $\dot x = -x +\dot f$, $x(0) = f(0)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Okay, I can see that if you differentiate both sides, you obtain a differential equation. But what is the practical application of the *inverse operator* in this scenario? Does it somehow lead to a solution?

Comment: @askquestions4: For continuously differentiable $f$ the integral equation is, as I said, equivalent to the initial value problem. So by solving the integral equation one solves the initial value problem. That's a standard step (in fact, for more general equations) in the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I understand that the problem is equivalent to a differential equation, I understand you can solve that differential equation using standard techniques because it is a linear ODE. What I don't understand is, why would anyone care about the *inverse operator* that describes the initial problem?

Comment: The inverse operator gives you the solution: the equation $Ax = f$ is obviously equivalent to $x = A^{-1} f$. I'm not sure I understand what precisely you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble seeing "how" it gives you the solution, though I have a better idea now. I've never solved an ODE by using an "inverse operator", so this is news to me, I solve it with standard integration techniques or the laplace transform.

Comment: @askquestions4: I'm under the impression that you are really overinterpreting the problem. If I understand correctly, this problem was a homework problem that was discussed in another question. Integral equations are, in general, an important tool in various scientific models, so it is important to study them. In this specific example, the integral equation happens to be (i) equivalent to an initial value problem, and to be (ii) related to spectral theory (the problem is equivalent to computing the resolvent of minus the Volterra operator at the point $1$). [...]

Comment: [...] As mentioned above, the problem is also related to the more general proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs with Lipschitz right hand side; and in the particular example you describe, everything is linear, so this example can be used as a nice illustration of how Banach's contraction mapping principle (that is employed in the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem) is a non-linear generalisation of the Neumann series (that can be used to compute the inverse of $\operatorname{id}-A$ for certain operators $A$. [...]

Comment: [...] In other words: It's simply a nice exercise since it brings together many different themes and ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed replies, this method of solving ODE is new to me. Are there ever circumstances where solving ODEs (or PDEs?) in this capacity would be preferable?